# Cannot get collections by date with mongoose

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose

I can not query the collection filtering by a date

The following code is that I have so far

```
//The following code shows how my schema is:

date: {type: Date, required: true}

//This is a date from a collection in MongoDB:
date: 2019-09-06T16:48:14.000+00:00

//This is how I saved the date in the MongoDB:
"2019/09/09 08:55:15"

//And this is how I perform the query in NodeJS:

let year = req.query.year;
let month = req.query.month;
let day = req.query.day;

let startDate = new Date(year, month, day);
let endDate = new Date(year, month, day);

// find documents in MongoDB
let query = SALES.find({ date: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }});

// execute the query at a later time
query.exec(function (err, item) { // item is a dictionary
    if (err) return handleError(err); // throws an error if any
    if (item === null || item.length === 0) {
        res.json({
            status: 'empty',
        });
    }
    else {
        res.json({
            salesRecord: item
        });
     }
});
```

I read that is easy to get, but I am not able to do it. Any help is welcome

I have not error on the query, simply I get the response as empty.
The expected results is to get the dates from the specified date

Comment: Can you show your `req.query`?

Comment: The req.query has the values for example: year = 2019, month = 08, day = 09, etc

Comment: Your `startDate` and `endDate` have the same value so the record in your db need to have exactly same date as `new Date(year, month, day)`

Comment: yes, they have it, and the query does not works ;(

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Date you saved("2019/09/09 08:55:15") is being treated as a string.

Try this:

```
db.mycollection.find({
    "date" : {"$gte": new Date()}
})
```

or

```
db.mycollection.find({
    "date" : {"$gte": ISODate(new Date())} // current date
});
```

**Description**

Mongodb shell provides various methods to return the date.It can be a string or as a Date object:

1. Date() method which returns the current date as a string.
2. new Date() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.
3. ISODate() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.